# Setting a rotation transformation to a UIView or its layer doesn't seem to work?

Tags: iphone, uiview, rotation, calayer

I'm trying to have one of the children views in my screen (owned by one view controller) *not* rotate when the device rotates. My view controller allows rotations as it should, and I'm trying to apply a 90-degree rotation to the one "stationary" view to counteract the overall rotation.

Problem is, everything seems to rotate anyways, and the transform doesn't seem to do anything. I've attempted with an affine transform on the view, and with a 3d transform on the layer (below). The method is getting called, but I never see a visual difference.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    CALayer *layer = stuckview.layer;
    layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(90, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To help others find this, I'm adding a couple searchable phrases, like:

prevent a UIView from rotating

prevent a UITableView background from rotating

stop a UIView rotation

stop a UITableView background rotation

---

A complete sample for any orientation:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
    {
        switch (toInterfaceOrientation) {
            case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
                stuckview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2); // 90 degress
                break;
            case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
                stuckview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI + M_PI_2); // 270 degrees
                break;
            case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
                stuckview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI); // 180 degrees
                break;
            default:
                stuckview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I check and find that UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown is not working in ios 6.

Comment: is stuckview a CALAyer or a UIView?

Comment: @AdamWaite - A UIView, as indicated by the name and description! ;-)

Comment: CGAffineTransforms are for Views not for Layers. So the answer is not what was the question.

Comment: @OlSen - The question was to transform the view or layer, as stated in the title and question, with either an affine transform on the view, or a 3D transform on the layer.

Answer (score 5):

Is your code actually executed? (Do you implement shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: ?)

```
stuckview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
```

should do the job.

Note: The functions take radians not degrees.